# In Ionic 7, how do I embed a hamburger menu in my header bar alongside other components?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, header, hamburger-menu, ionic7

I'm using Ionic 7 and React 18.  I would like to design an Ionic hamburger menu for my application, taht I would like to reside in the upper right of my toolbar.  I have designed this Menu.tsx component

```
const Menu: React.FC = () =>
{

  const onClickHandler = (): void =>
  {
    menuController.close();
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <IonMenu
        side="start"
        menuId="first"
        content-id="menuContent"
        swipe-gesture={true}
        disabled={false}
        maxEdgeStart={100}
        hidden={false}
        type="overlay">
        <IonHeader translucent>
          <IonToolbar color="primary">
            <IonTitle>
              <IonIcon slot="start" icon={menuOutline}></IonIcon>
            </IonTitle>
            <IonButtons slot="start">
              <IonMenuButton
                autoHide={true}
                onClick={() => onClickHandler()}
              ></IonMenuButton>
            </IonButtons>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        <IonContent>
          <IonList>
            <IonItem>Menu Item</IonItem>
            <IonItem>Menu Item</IonItem>
            <IonItem>Menu Item</IonItem>
            <IonItem>Menu Item</IonItem>
            <IonItem>Menu Item</IonItem>
          </IonList>
        </IonContent>
      </IonMenu>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

and then I have put it on my App.tsx page in the IonHeader bar

```
          <IonHeader>
      <IonToolbar>
        <IonButtons slot='start'>
          <IonButton>
            <IonIcon icon={logoReact} />
          </IonButton>
        </IonButtons>
        <IonTitle>My site</IonTitle>
        <IonButtons slot='end'>
          <IonButton>
            <IonIcon icon={personCircle} />
          </IonButton>
        </IonButtons>
        <Menu/>
      </IonToolbar>
    </IonHeader>
```

However, this does not display, per my demo -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/an5yjh-vhnvgg?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMenu.tsx,src%2FApp.tsx .  What else do I need to do to get my hamburger menu to appear?

Comment: stackblitz in not workng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but some adjustments required to make it work:

1. add the `<Menu/>` element as a direct child of the `<IonApp>` element.
2. set the id of `<IonContent>` inside the App.tsx the same id in the menu element. so, `menuContent` This will enable dragging behaviour to open the drawer

Bonus:
I also added the menu button in the toolbar, so users can open the menu with that button as well.
Also make the IonPage element as root, so your layout works!

[Updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/an5yjh-9dghsz?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

Menu.tsx:

```
...
      <IonMenu
        side="start" // this puts the toolbar on the left side for ltr locales
        menuId="first"
        content-id="menuContent" // you should also use the same id in App.
        swipe-gesture={true}
        disabled={false}
        maxEdgeStart={100}
        hidden={false}
        type="overlay">
    ...
```

App.tsx

```
...
export default function App() {
  return (
    <IonApp>
      <Menu />
      <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonButtons slot="start">
            <IonMenuButton/>
          </IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>My site</IonTitle>
          <IonButtons slot="end">
            <IonButton>person</IonButton>
          </IonButtons>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
        <IonContent className="ion-padding" id="menuContent">
          <p>Hi there</p>
        </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    </IonApp>
  );
}
```